# Unable to post new entity with relationship using RestTemplate and Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm struggling on how to use Spring's RestTemplate with the hateoas module to create new related entities.
I've tried fetching a Foo object and assigning it to the Bar object I'm trying to create.  When I post that the server gives me a Http 400 Bad Request.  When I tried to post a Resource object with a link, I get
this exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.hateoas.Resource]
```

I'm at a loss for figuring out how to create the correct POST request using RestTemplate against a Spring Data REST service.

Background:
I have two classes Foo and Bar.  Foo has a OneToMany relationship with Bar and thus Bar has a ManyToOne relationship with Foo.

The code for each class is as follows:

Foo:

```
package com.foo;

//Imports omitted for clarity

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="Foo", schema="dbo")
public class Foo implements Identifiable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @Column(name="FOO_I")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="descript")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="foo")  
    private Set<Bar> bars;
}
```

Bar:

```
package com.foo;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="Bar", schema="dbo")
public class Bar implements Identifiable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @Column(name="BAR_I")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="barname")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="bardescription")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="qty")
    private int qty;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FOO_I", referencedColumnName="FOO_I", nullable=false) 
    private Foo foo;
}
```

I'm attempting to post to http://nonexistantdomain.com.mx.uk.ch:8080/bars to create a new bar that is related to a foo whose FOO_I is 1.

I can see output from things like http://nonexistantdomain.com.mx.uk.ch:8080/foos/1 and http://nonexistantdomain.com.mx.uk.ch:8080/foos/1/bars and http://nonexistantdomain.com.mx.uk.ch:8080/bars/5.  So I know the relationships are working.

Further I'm able to create a new bar using wget and the following post body to http://nonexistantdomain.com.mx.uk.ch:8080/bars/:

```
{
  "name": "newWgetBar",
  "description": "just another bar",
  "qty": 2,
  "foo" : "http://nonexistantdomain.com.mx.uk.ch:8080/foos/1"
}
```

Which works successfully.  How can I use Spring's RestTemplate to do this so I can accomplish what I need from my java code?

Edit:

Here are the examples I have tried.

```
private RestTemplate acquireTemplate(boolean isHalJson) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();                       
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
    mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());        

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/hal+json"));
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

    return new RestTemplate(Collections.<HttpMessageConverter<?>> singletonList(converter));
}

public void addABar(String name) {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.setName(name);
    b.setDescription("An added bar.");
    b.setQty(2);
    RestTemplate template = acquireTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<Foo> f = template.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/foos/1", Foo.class);
    Link l = new Link("foo","http://localhost:8080/foos/1");
    Resource<Bar> r = new Resource<Bar>(b,l);       
    URI i = template.postForLocation("http://localhost:8080/bars", r);
}

public void addABarAttempt2(String name) {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.setName(name);
    b.setDescription("An added bar.");
    b.setQty(2);
    RestTemplate template = acquireTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<Foo> f = template.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/foos/1", Foo.class);
    b.setFoo(f.getBody());
    URI i = template.postForLocation("http://localhost:8080/bars", b);
}

public void addABarAttempt3(String name) {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.setName(name);
    b.setDescription("An added bar.");
    b.setQty(2);
    RestTemplate template = acquireTemplate();
    template.put("http://localhost:8080/foos/1/bars",b);
}
```

All three examples fail for differing reasons.

Comment: Let's see if I understand the question, you cannot create a new Bar instance via post that has the desired "Foo" set. If you cannot create a new Bar, why are you able to see the relationships and the bar object? If you could not create a new bar, there shouldn't be a bar object right?

Comment: How are you making this post request ? Javascript ?

Comment: Please provide full stack trace + client java code (which tries to create bar)

Comment: @yunandtidus The post request is being made from Java.

Comment: @Tornn client java code has been added.

Answer (score 2):

What about use this code:

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        String uri = new String("url");

        Bar b= new Bar();
        bar.setName("newWgetBar");

        rt.postForObject(uri, b, Bar.class);
```

it would be usefull if you show us what do you program so far on your RestTemplate